# отменить https замену для внешних ссылок

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, php-fpm, cloudflare

Подключил через cloudflare SSL и переадресация на https. Все работает но у меня картинки с внешнего ресурса в которого нету поддержки https а Google Chrome теперь все ссылки на сайте заменяет на https.
Как запретить замену ссылок для внешнего ресурса?
Система Ларавел на nginx

Answer (score 0):

[image: переход на https]

Оказалось что браузеры уже не дают возможность использовать http на сайте еслы вы перешли на https

Comment: это из страницы Firefox